# Replaced storage controller, now can't find ESXi ZFS mount point

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, storage, zfs, infiniband

We have an older file server (running Gentoo of all things) that recently suffered a storage controller failure. The parts were replaced and everything is back online except one item, probably the most important: the ESXi mount point.

The former sysadmin, while brilliant, never kept notes for any changes. There's nothing in `FSTAB` or `CRONTAB` or any 'normal' place to create mounts. Running `zfs list` shows all the ZFS mount names, but has a blank for the mount point. My coworker and I are poring through log files trying to find any indication of historical mounts, but there's nothing. This is connected to the open-source licensed compute server via infiniband, but unsure whether it's shared via NFS, iSCSI, or what. Like I said, no notes to work from.

Comment: Anything in `/etc/exports`?

Comment: Nothing, however, I was reading another thread that I checked before I posted this and ran a `hexdump -C </dev/ | head -40` on two partitions that showed up as unformatted during a `fdisk -l`. The curious thing is that part of the output shows this in the right margin:

`naa.6001405caf12eb39b604499954050669:1`

looks like ESXi volume to me, but I'm unfamiliar with the `hexdump` command.

Comment: `zfs get mountpoint all` ?

Comment: @ewwhite that lists all the mountpoints, but is missing a value for our share. For example, there is a share for our Xenserver called `xenserver-vhd`, and it's got a corresponding mountpoint called the same. The value for `esxivhd`, but the value is merely `-`.

Answer (score 1):

This is *so* little information to go on, but I'll try to edit this answer as needed...

Please show the output of:

`zpool list`
`zpool status -v`
`zfs list`

And possibly http://pastebin.com the `zpool history` output for me.

---

Okay, that fileserver [is a terrible mess](http://pastebin.com/zvD4SsdR). I'm sorry your organization is in this situation without documentation.

I'm actually concerned about how this was done... It's a perfect example of unpaid technical debt... but the core issue is that your Xen and VMware shares are not NFS. They are comprised of ZFS zvols here. That means that ZFS is presenting a block device to the hypervisors that's formatted using their native filesystems. I don't know if iSCSI is in the mix here, but if you post `zpool history`, I may be able to determine what was done.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zvD4SsdR

Comment: There's only one mention of `/tank/esxvhd` that that's it's creation in 2015. http://pastebin.com/7jDhvNke

Comment: That's correct. It's a non-sparse ZFS zvol. Please post `zfs get all tank/esxvhd`

Comment: cannot open 'tank/esxvhd': dataset does not exist

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5N2dMh3i

Comment: The block device is exported somehow to ESXi. Have you tried rescanning storage LUNs on the ESXi side? We may need to examine that setup, too.

Comment: Yeah I've rescanned a couple times before the weekend and did so again today, just in case. No dice.

Comment: @ChristianHolton This is beyond the level of help I can provide for free online. This is definitely solvable, but is something I'd set up a normal support engagement for. My contact information is in my [ServerFault profile page](http://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite?tab=profile). Your previous engineer left a bit of a mess and constructed a fragile solution. You may want to contact them to see if there's a quick fix.

Comment: @ChristianHolton It's definitely something I can repair, but just not through this forum or medium. The consulting offer stands.